# Why doesn't this regex output correctly?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var re = /apples/gi;  
var str = "Apples are round, and apples are juicy.";  
var newstr = str.replace("apples", "oranges","gi");
document.write(newstr);
```

It should output `oranges are round, and oranges are juicy.` , because of the case insensitivity, but instead it outputs `Apples are round, and oranges are juicy.`

Why??

Comment: It is listed as "non-standard": https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the `str.replace` function only has [two parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), not three.

So I would guess you have to write

```
var newstr = str.replace(/apples/gi, "oranges");
```

instead.

Answer (score 3):

There's no [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with that signature, instead use the regex you created, like this:

```
var re = /apples/gi;  
var str = "Apples are round, and apples are juicy.";  
var newstr = str.replace(re, "oranges");
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/pRCBu/).

Answer (score 2):

The `re` variable in your example is not in use for some reason.

```
var str = "Apples are round, and apples are juicy.";  
var newstr = str.replace(/apples/gi, "oranges");
document.write(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var str = "Apples are round, and apples are juicy.";  
var newstr = str.replace(/apples/gi, "oranges");
document.write(newstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You never use the `re` variable and the third argument for String.replace() is non-standard so it won't work in all browsers:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace